# disprove: $\forall A,B,C(A\cup B=A\cup C \Rightarrow B=C)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, examples-counterexamples

If I let $A=\emptyset$,$B=C=\{x\}$, do I have a valid counterexample?

Comment: Try $A=\{1\}$, $B=\{1,2\}$, and $C=\{2\}$.

Comment: No, "Disprove $\forall A,B,C \, (A\cup B=A\cup C \Rightarrow B=C)$" means that you need to find three sets $A,B,C$ such that $A\cup B=A\cup C \nRightarrow B=C$, that is, $A\cup B=A\cup C$ and $B \neq C$ (recall that $p \Rightarrow q$ is the same as saying that $\neg p$ or $q$).

Comment: @azif00 Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Simple counterexample $B\subset A$ and $C\subset A$. Then $A=A\cup B=A\cup C$.  There is no other relationship between $B$ and $C$.  Simple choice, make $C=A-B$.